# Two FTDI devices

Tags: uart, ftdi

I have two devices which use FTDI chips to communicate with a computer. Will it be possible to communicate between them using a USB cable?

For one of the devices I have complete control over the firmware, for the other one I don’t.  What I am trying to achieve is communication between two embedded devices via UART but I only have access to the interfaces after the FTDI chips.

Something I’m thinking of is generating some kind of code, so that I can send a message from my device (the one I can control the firmware) to make the other device believe that there is a computer on the other side.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you don't just connect the serial ports together without the FTDI in between?

Comment: "i only have access to the the interfaces after the FTDI chips" - I presume "after" means the USB side

Comment: Generally speaking a determined person could bypass the USB-serial chips; quite likely there are test points downstream of them, and even if not it's typically only 2 signals to pick up.   Otherwise, a flash-MCU based USB host, while taking longer than a pi to get going, will be far more robust, and potentially low power in operation.

Comment: FTDI made a microcontroller with a USB host with special support for other FTDI devices (plus HID and mass storage).  However it (Vinculum) never had good tooling and is pretty well abandoned.  Other MCUs are going to have a terrible time talking to an FTDI due to the fact that it uses a non-standard protocol.

Comment: @BenVoigt - no, other MCUs are not going to have a terrible time.  The protocol is very well understood, as evidenced by the fact that there's been a Linux driver since basically forever, there are implementations atop Android's userspace USB host API, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Ok, but it's still a significant porting effort to get one of those running on an actual MCU, because the abstraction level is totally different.

Comment: @BenVoigt - actually it's not very different at all, since they're all just wrapping the same underlying types of USB operations.  Further, there are already MCU versions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yeah but the Linux (and Android) ones have to use split interrupt handlers and such.

Comment: @BenVoigt - you're mixing up host and device considerations.  USB is timed by the host.  Also, Android USB API is a *userspace* one.  As is something like libusb on linux.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: ... and userspace is an abstraction level that doesn't exist on an MCU either.

Comment: @BenVoigt - userspace is only relevant in demonstrating that interrupts and kernel paradigms are not required for such an API.  **If you had ever actually tried** such a porting exercise - as I have - you'd know it's not nearly as complicated as you imagine from your perspective lacking any actual knowledge of the subject.  Frankly for something like this where you configure it and then just keep servicing it, often all you have to do is use something like wireshark to capture a few packets between your PC and it, and then do the same thing in your own code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I may not have done "porting" but I have written peripheral control code for both MCUs and desktop OSes and it's nothing alike.  Number crunching stuff can be used between embedded and desktop just by passing the code to the cross-compiler.  Hardware access is extremely specific to the environment.  Sure, there will be reusable pieces for processing the buffers after you get them from the low-level layer -- as long as the low-level layer on both platforms uses the same paradigm.  If one is event-driven and the other uses blocking calls, good luck.

Comment: @BenVoigt - if you had every actually tried **the USB task** you'd realize how irrelevant what you are arguing really is.  But because you've never done so, you just continue spouting falsely imagined difficulties.  Seriously, **give it an actual try** - document what you need to do by studying the PC implementation, then get an example that does similar types of operations for the embedded platform, and modify it to do what you documented as required.   You'll be surprised how straightforward it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to FT232 or the like. In that case your plan can't work, because those chips are USB *slave* devices, and two USB slaves can't talk to each other.

To connect them, you'd need a USB host with two ports, the FTDI driver installed, and a small app that copies characters from one (virtual) serial port to the other. Quite feasible with a Raspberry Pi.